# Html/Css chose one over the other ruleset

Tags: html, css

I'm brand new to Html/CSS (and, well, programming). From the tutorials I've been learning from, CSS picks the last ruleset when there are two for the same thing. I'm creating a blog-like website (a title, then a thumbnail, then some text, then a read more button, each on its own line). I am using the article tag. I want the tag to have different properties when on a computer or a phone. I've written this:

```
article{
    background:pink;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:column wrap;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
    width: 75vw;  
}

@media (orientation: portrait){
    article{
        background:orange;
        display:flex;
        flex-flow:column wrap;
        padding-bottom: 10%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        align-items: center;
        width:100vw;
    }
}
```

The color changes as intended, but the width stays at 75vw. What I want is to have the article block occupy just some part of the width when on a computer but the whole width when on a mobile phone. The background color is just to help see the changes when programming, I'll remove it after.

I would appreciate it a lot if someone can explain to me what I got wrong and how I am supposed to do this correctly.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I don't know this for sure, but it could be that a non-mobile device is always considered 'portrait', so the media query won't do anything. (Although, why would the bg change? I don't know.) You might need more info than just 'orientation'. Maybe a 'max-width' would help. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: I understand using a different background for testing, but you can also get rid of all the duplicates; if a style isn't changing then you don't need it in the media query.